# Magento pages loading in one line

Tags: magento-1.9, styles, slow-response

This may not be a Magento issue but i am currently being asked to try and stop the our home page loading the way it does for one of my clients. I have been told the site never loaded like this before but now that its been noticed its driving my client crazy.

When our site [www.calzeat.com](https://calzeat.com) loads you will notice it all loads in a line for a split second and then loads properly. I hardly notice it at all but i have decent connection here but my clients machine be it the internet or old machine this takes a good few seconds longer.

Has anyone ever experienced this before and is there a solution? I will be forever grateful as i am hearing about this issue daily :)